# Want to replace push-button with IR receiver

Tags: timer, infrared, 555, latching

In the diagram below I want to replace that push-button switch Sw1 with IR receiver, I tried a lot with different combination with IR receiver and tried with transistor but I failed, so, please how can I achieve that.
[image]

thanks for advice.

Comment: smells like an XY problem .... what is your end goal?

Comment: I want to control that circuit via IR Tx Rx. So, I want to replace the Sw1 with IR Receiver to be able to control it with IR Tx

Comment: If recommend checking this out https://www.electronics-lab.com/project/infrared-toggle-switch-for-home-appliances/

Comment: @MY, the end goal appears to be something related to the relay

Comment: I believe the end goal is about latching on or off the relay via IR remote.

Comment: @Leoman12 thanks, but I want to use timer 555 and not 4017 IC.

Comment: you can use the 555 but you will need to add a solid-state relay controlled by the IR receiver.  the 4017 is a cheaper solution.

Comment: @MY Ok sure. There is a way to do it but can you provide the IR receiver part number?

Comment: @Leoman12 the part number is : PT333-3B

Comment: @ MY Are you using a remote control or just a IR diode with constant dc current as transmitter?

Comment: @Leoman12  just an IR transmitter diode and resistor with constant dc current.

Comment: While you've failed to state exactly what this is supposed to do, realistically systems like this just will not work very well without an MCU or fixed function remote decoder IC that looks for a pattern and changes state momentarily or lastingly as a result. It will be far better in the long run to get rid of the 555 as well and fold its functionality into the MCU.  You'll find many Arduino projects that could serve as an introduction to the idea, which you might then minimize to an ATtiny or similar.

Comment: @Chris Stratton I should use timer 555 or a smaller alternative for sake for size and cost, the over all project will be fit in 4x1.5 cm.

Comment: That's another reason why you should use an MCU.  Look at the size of a relatively easy to work with SOIC-8 package for an ATtiny85 (or if you must, DIP-8).  Essentially all you need is that, a bypass cap, and the IR receiver blob.  If you need to drive the relay add a resistor, transistor and catch diode.  But get it working first using something like an Arduino board to become familiar with the *concepts* before you add the complication of making a size reduced version.

Answer (score -1):

Information given: IR receiver PT333-3B phototransistor, Transmitting circuit is IR diode with constant dc current when turned on, and desire to use latching circuit via IR receiver instead of pushbutton switch.

Based on the information and given the circuit that you want modified there is a way to  adapt the circuit to your needs. Unfortunately, because the switch 1 in your circuit is connected between two nodes that aren't typical for use with a simple transistor. However a signal relay is appropriate since a relay is simply a controlled switch. The G5V-1-DC12 relay is an example of one relay that can be used since it's for low power signaling. In addition to signal relay is the circuit to trigger turn on the relay from phototransistor. Here a phototransistor will turn on the PNP transistor and thus turn on the relay. [image]

Comment: Oh, that is component overhead, is there any other way without using the relay that you added ?

Comment: What do you mean “overhead”? With this circuit a relay would be ideal. I myself, don’t see another option unless you use another circuit.

Comment: Also if you mean like overhead costs, the relay isn’t too much. You can also use any appropriate signal relay and it could be cheaper. And I have found when you add the functionality of IR receiver or an output from something other than a physical switch to a latching circuit, it is a rather difficult thing to do. This is due to the nature of how the latch is triggered.

Comment: @MY don't waste your time building this. This proposal is absurd in its method for what it attempts to do, and additionally has the fatal oversight of having no immunity to ambient light sources since it not only doesn't look for a pulse code, but doesn't even look for the traditional 38 KHz or similar carrier that actual IR remote receivers do.

Comment: @chris Stratton, perhaps you’d like to propose a solution then?

Comment: It happens that I already did propose a path to an actual, viable solution general enough to cover whatever the unspecified actual goal is, though the lack of specificity makes the question off-topic here and an actual "answer" impossible.  More generally, "what is your answer?" is **decidedly not** a valid response to criticism of the obvious flaws of your posting.  Pointing out that something is so fatally wrong would be entirely appropriate even if one were not offering a viable alternative.

Comment: @Leoman12 I mean overhead in size and cost because the over all product will be fit in nearly 4x1.5 cm.